# How can I make spring-boot-devtools work without @EnableAutconfiguration or @SpringBootApplication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I'm working on an application using spring-boot v1.3.5.RELEASE, which doesn't use `@SpringBootApplication` nor `@EnableAutconfiguration` (customer requirement).

I want to enable `spring-boot-devtools` to have the "restart" feature in my IDE. I've put it as dependency, hit `mvn spring-boot:run`. the restarter works:

```
DEBUG o.s.b.d.r.Restarter - Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]
DEBUG o.s.b.d.r.Restarter - Immediately restarting application
DEBUG o.s.b.d.r.Restarter - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@22843e39
DEBUG o.s.b.d.r.Restarter - Starting application application.Application with URLs [file:/D:/git/repos/...]
```

But it doesn't reload after IDE code modification and rebluid (Ctrl+B on eclipse).

The problem seems to be that devtools relies on `@EnableAutconfiguration` (factories loaded with the `META-INF/spring.factories`) to be configured (and I can't use this annotation).
Basically, I need to do that by myself (see below the content of the devtools `spring.factories` file):

```
# Application Initializers
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScopeInitializer
# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener
# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.RemoteDevToolsAutoConfiguration
# Environment Post Processors
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsHomePropertiesPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor
# Restart Listeners
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartListener=\
org.springframework.boot.devtools.log4j2.Log4J2RestartListener
```

How can I do that (I'm not particulary fluent in spring-boot lingua) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to `@Import` the DevTools auto-configuration classes that you want to use via a `@Configuration` class of your own. You may not want the remote support, in which case the following should suffice:

```
@Configuration
@Import({LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.class, DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
class ManaulDevToolsConfiguration {

}
```

In the unlikely event that you want to use a bean of your own in place of any of DevTools' auto-configured beans, you'll need to order things carefully to ensure that your beans are defined before the DevTools auto-configuration classes are imported and the evaluation of any on missing bean conditions is performed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried the solution but it doesn't work: It seems that the restarter feature needs also the application initializer and listeners to work.

Comment: So I've made a spring "profile" and added in properties "context.initializer.classes" and "context.listener.classes". That's doing the trick.
But I have no solutions for Environment post processors (need this to overload "spring-devtools.properties" in my HOME) and restart listener (don't know if it is useful - we use log4j in our app).
Have you an hint for these (register env. post processor & restart listener) ? That would be great.

Comment: They should be loaded without using auto-configuration via `SpringApplication` or `SpringApplicationBuilder`.

Comment: I agree with you for `ApplicationContextInitializer` and `ApplicationListener` (I used properties because on this project I can't modify `SpringApplication`), but for the others (`EnvironmentPostProcessor` and `RestartListener`), I'm stuck...